# Are there any risks when allowing only HTTPS traffic to a SP site?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, configuration, alternate-access-mapping

We'd like to do away with any pesky additional AAMs, and also not have to worry about extending our web applications more than we need to - our implementation is very straightforward, and having extra wiring on the back end that allows for HTTP traffic seems unnecessary.

*We use NTLM under classic-mode over HTTPS 99.9999% of the time for all traffic inside and outside the network.*

Can anyone forsee any problems with only allowing https traffic to a particular site?

We'd also like to do away with access from the machine name (http://machineName)

Example:

(https://portal.contoso.com) for the site

and

(https://portal.contoso.com:1234) for central admin

Workable alternatives to this are good too. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer SSL-only, FQDN-only URLs.  It simplifies management and user experience.  SSL adds some network traffic overhead, but on today's networks it is fairly insignificant (high latency networks would be the exception).